# Window (Changing mode doesn't fire event like resize)

Tags: events, window, vaadin, vaadin7

Like the topic said I'm having problem with window resizing event. Basically  I want to my content fit window size. However not everything works like it should. Changing window mode for instance maximizing or resizing is handled by client event listener. The problem is that when I'm resizing everything works ok, but maximizing/restoring only changes window size and the content doesnt fit at all. What is the solution for this type of behaviour?

ps. Changing browser's window size fire the content to update.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't need to use resize listener to do layouting in Vaadin Window, usually full size layouts (width and height are 100%) and expand rations are the concepts you need.

If you really need to use window resize listeners, you need to use a `WindowModeChangeListener`. That's fired when window mode is changes. There is a method called `addWindowModeChangeListener` in `Window`.

Comment: Hi Henry, I am having the same issue. What do you mean with "full size layouts" ? I mean, in my case I want to have the window in a fixed size (for instance 700 px width). The content inside is having a full size (setSizeFull())

Comment: @AydinK I mean setSizeFull(). Just define a fixed size for your window.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for me (yet). I've a window with fixed width (700px) and relative height (90%). Inside there is a Tabsheet with setSizeFull. In case I maximize the window, I need to toggle the Tabsheets so that the layout repositioning/repaint occurs. Otherwise (without Tabsheet content switching) the content has same size after maximizing :-/